# How to use textwrapper in python for file manipulation

Tags: python

Im trying to write an output file that limits the characters per line to 60 characters. I managed to read the text file in and make it 60 characters per line, however it added words that werent suppose to be on the same line. For example, the read in file was

```
Albuquerque is my turkey and he's feathered and he's fine, And he
wobbles and he gobbles and he's
absolutely mine

He's the best pet you can get yet better than
a dog or cat, He's my albuquerque turkey and i'm awfully proud of that
```

after using a text wrapper method

```
Albuquerque is my turkey and he's feathered and he's fine,
And he wobbles and he gobbles and he's absolutely mine  He's

the best pet you can get yet better than a dog or cat, He's
my albuquerque turkey and i'm awfully proud of that
```

and it should be

```
Albuquerque is my turkey and he’s feathered and he’s fine,
And he wobbles and he gobbles and he’s absolutely mine

He’s the best pet you can get yet, better than a dog or cat,
He’s my albuquerque turkey and i’m awfully proud of that
```

How can i adjust the text wrapper method to accommodate the sentences?

```
def adjust_linelength():
    with open("essay_neb.txt") as file:
        text = file.read().strip()
    with open("essay_final.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(textwrap.fill(text, width=60))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [textwrap documentation for 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html),

> textwrap.fill(text[, width[, ...]])
>
> Wraps the single paragraph in text, and returns a single string containing the wrapped paragraph.

If you break your text up into paragraphs first, then run the textwrapper on each paragraph, it should work.